# Limited number of possible choices?

Tags: java

Java newbie here.

There is this code (from tutorial) and i was wondering, what loop or other method i should use to limit max guess choices  for example to 3?
I mean that user can guess only limited number of times and after that program just stops.

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int secretNum;
        int guess;
        boolean correct = false;

        Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("GIVE ME SECRET NUMBER");
        secretNum = keybord.nextInt();

        while (!correct){
            System.out.println("GUESS: ");
            guess = keybord.nextInt();

            if (guess == secretNum){
                correct = true;
                System.out.println("YOU ARE RIGHT");
            }
            else if (guess < secretNum){
                System.out.println("HIGHER");
            }
            else if (guess > secretNum) System.out.println("LOWER");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way to head towards the answer is to say in words what you want to happen. Currently your code says "repeat while not correct" you want to say "repeat while not correct or we have tried too many times" this leads you to count attempts and use an an "or" in your while (as shown in Alan Sereb's answer"), The big trick here is let your thinking lead you to investigate how to do an "or" and how to count the attempts; rather than look for the code as such, look for the constructs to build the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the number of attempts with a counter like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int attempts = 0;
    Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("GIVE ME SECRET NUMBER");
    int secretNum = keybord.nextInt();

    while (true){
        System.out.println("GUESS: ");
        int guess = keybord.nextInt();
        attempts++;

        if (guess == secretNum){
            System.out.println("YOU ARE RIGHT");
            break;
        }
        if (attempts == 3) {
            System.out.println("Max attempts!");
            break;
        }
        else if (guess < secretNum){
            System.out.println("HIGHER");
        }
        else if (guess > secretNum) System.out.println("LOWER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do with your clean code structure. Declare a variable outside of your loop which will store the number of attempts. Then in your loop condition check amount of attempts and in the body increment this variable.

```
// Add
int attempts = 0;

// Update condition
while (!correct || attempts <= 3) {

    // Update variable at the end of the loop
    attempts++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A do-while loop is best suited for this. 
It is guaranteed to execute at least once, validate the loop condition at the end of the loop instead of the beginning, and it's easy to break out of any loop when you have breaking condition like this.

```
int guesses = 0;
final maxGuesses = 3;
final secretNum = ...

do {
    System.out.println("GUESS: ");
        guess = keybord.nextInt();

        if (guess == secretNum){
            System.out.println("YOU ARE RIGHT");
            break; // no need for 'correct' value, just break out of the loop
        }
        else if (guess < secretNum){
            System.out.println("HIGHER");
        }
        else if (guess > secretNum) System.out.println("LOWER");
}while (guesses++ < maxGuesses)
```

A for loop will also work. Here, guesses is checked before the loop starts, and increments at the end.

```
for(int guesses = 0; guesses < maxGuesses; guesses++){
    System.out.println("GUESS: ");
     guess = keybord.nextInt();

     if (guess == secretNum){
         System.out.println("YOU ARE RIGHT");
         break;// no need for 'correct' value, just break out of the loop
     }
     else if (guess < secretNum){
         System.out.println("HIGHER");
     }
     else if (guess > secretNum) System.out.println("LOWER");
}
```